# Binding class data on DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am having trouble showing the Address portion of my Customer class, i have made an Location property that show the whole address but when i run the application the address is missing. As you can see in the image the Customer binds to the data grid.

[image]

If i can not find a solution i will just add the address properties to my Customer class, but i would like to solve if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Example instance:

```
var customer = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = fNameTxt.Text, LastName = lNameTxt.Text, Email = emailTxt.Text, Phone = phTxt.Text,
            Address = new Address { Street = streetTxt.Text, Suburb = suburbTxt.Text, City = cityTxt.Text, Country = countryTxt.Text }
        };
```

XAML: (datagrid)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="customerDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="780" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Full Name" Binding="{Binding FullName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding Phone}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    private static int counter = 0;
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Id = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Location { get { return string.Format($"{Street}, {Suburb}, {City}, {Country}"); } }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
```

Email is a property of Customer class, so binding path `Email` in binding `{Binding Path=Email}` is resolved succesfully and email is shown.

But here `{Binding Path=Location}` binding path `Location` is wrong. Location is a property of Address class. Customer has only Address property of type Address. This makes Location a nested property. Binding should be changed:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address.Location}"/>
```

compare it with c# code:

```
var c = new Customer();
string location = c.Location; // ! won't compile
string location = c.Address.Location; // will compile, but give NullReferenceException, because Address wasn't initialized
```

as a last note: Visual Studio should have written multiple binding errors in Output window about Location property not found in Customer object. always check Output if binding doesn't work

Comment: Brilliant explanation thank you for clearing that up! In VS it did not alert me with the error and have checked the list. I have always bound properties from a single class. Top marks for explanation!